# What is the minimum degree of the polynomial?

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime number. What is the minimum degree of a monic polynomial $q(x)$ with integer coefficients such that $q(0),q(1),\ldots,q(p-1)$ are all $(p-1)$-powers of distinct integers?

The polynomial $q(x) = x^{p-1}$ satisfies the conditions, so we know that the minimum degree is less than or equal to $p-1$. I then thought about taking cases based on the values of $q(0),q(1),\ldots,q(p-1)$. For example, if $q(0) = q(1) = \cdots = q(p-1) = 0$, then we have $q(x) = x(x-1) \cdots (x-(p-1))g(x) = (x^p-x)g(x)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$. How can we continue?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, but a start:

Suppose $q(k) = {a_k}^{p-1}$ for $0\le k \le p-1$.

By Fermat's Little Theorem, we know $q(k) \equiv 0, 1 \pmod{p}$ for all $0\le k \le p-1$, so we may write $$q(x) (q(x) - 1) = x(x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-p+1) g(x)$$ as an equality in $\mathbb{F}_p [x]$ (for some $g(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$). From this, we obtain the (probably weak) bound $\deg(q) \ge (p+1)/2$.

If $p$ does not divide $a_k$ for all $0\le k \le p-1$, then a similar argument improves this lower bound to $\deg(q) \ge p$.